# DynamoDB transaction

Tags: amazon-dynamodb, elixir

I have a Users table, with key {id: hash, email: range} and I want to create an user *only* if no user with the same email exists. I am trying to use a transaction, so I think I need to use a condition:

```
case Dynamo.transact_write_items([
           {
             :condition_check,
             {
               table_name(),
               %{id: user_id, email: email},
               condition_expression: "email <> :email",
               expression_attribute_values: [email: email]
             }
           },
           {
             :put,
             {
               table_name(),
               new_user
             }
           }
         ])
         |> ExAws.request() do
      {:ok, _} -> {:ok, new_user}
      {:error, _} -> {:error, "unable to create user"}
    end
```

This is not working, and I have the following questions:

1. in the key argument, in the condition, I have to specify: `%{id: user_id, email: email}`, but I have to specify `user_id`, which still does not exist, I have only generated it. How can I define a key with no value ?
2. I am having the following error: `Transaction request cannot include multiple operations on one item`, so I suppose that, given the way I have defined the key in the condition, it counts either the check and the put as two operations on the same entity. How can I check the existence of an entity in a consistent way (and so in a transaction) ?

The Elixir code here is of course not relevant, that's just the language I am using :)

Answer (score 0):

According to the doc, [no two actions can target the same item](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/APIReference/API_TransactWriteItems.html) when using transaction. I don't think this is what you are looking for.

You can however, [use conditional checks in regular operations](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/Expressions.ConditionExpressions.html#Expressions.ConditionExpressions.SimpleComparisons). From the doc for instance,

```sh
aws dynamodb update-item \
    --table-name ProductCatalog \
    --key '{"Id": {"N": "456"}}' \
    --update-expression "SET Price = Price - :discount" \
    --condition-expression "Price > :limit" \
    --expression-attribute-values file://values.json
```

will do the following:

- get item with given ID
- read the price and checks the condition against it
- update accordingly if the condition is met

If the condition is not met, then the query will fail with a specific code.

- note that `update` is actually an upsert
- You must know beforehand the `ID` of the item you are looking for (actually, you must know the hash key. It could be an ID, a username, or whathever you have chosen)
- Also, note that this is a unique query that is thus completely concurrent-safe.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Anyway, my scenario is different. I have to create an user, whose key is an `user_id` and an `email`. So, I can only use the `email` to lookup for the user, not the `user_id`. So, I should create somehow a check that takes into account _only_ the `email`, which is what I don't understand if it's possible or not. Also, the `email` is not the HASH key because it can be changed maybe in future, so I need something different (and I chose an `id`) to identify the user.

Comment: To update/create an item you must know its hash key beforehand. If you do, then just update the corresponding item, and you can use conditional check on any attribute.
If you don't know the id beforehand, then this is not possible. Making the email the hash key could be an option but this depends on your app

Comment: So, since I can't do the email the HASH key, I should lookup for the user entity _outside_ the transaction and then use its id, if present, to create a transaction with proper check. Makes any sense ?

Comment: It makes sense yes. A conditional expression is basically a mini transaction, saying that you should check condition and perform mutation at the same time. There can't be any race condition in the middle of that.